# Reset POST value of Objective HTML Channel Search on button click

Tags: objective-html

Pretty much after what the title says.

Is there a way to reset/unset a POST value if it is currently set utilizing a button. The idea here, is the button would be a filter of sorts, so clicking would remove certain portions of the URL if currently set.

As an example:
Say we have a button, `<a href="#" class="unsetFilter1">Remove filter 1</a>` and upon clicking, it would do something along the lines of checking
`{if '{exp:channel_search:is_set name="filter1"}' == 1}` where if **TRUE** (as the statement is setup), do something like `{exp:channel_search:reset name="filter1"}`

It seems possible, as all the components needed are there, just not sure how to actually set this up?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've got this figured out. Here's what I did:

```
{if '{exp:channel_search:is_set name="filter1"}' == 1}
    {!-- If here, the filter is applied, unset it and go back to page one as results will differ --}
    <a href="{exp:channel_search:url set:filter1='' set:page='1'}" class="button secondary disabled">Show locations that match filter1</a>
{if:else}
    {!-- If here, the filter is NOT applied, set it and go back to page one as results will differ --}
    <a href="{exp:channel_search:url set:filter1='SOME_TITLE_TO_FILTER' set:page='1'}" class="button secondary">Hide locations that match filter1</a>
{/if}
```

Basically, I'm checking if the variable is set, and if so get the current URL, unset the variable, set the page to 1 and go to this URL in click. Do the opposite if not set.

I added a default search rule to accomplish the filtering
[image]